# By the "Settings Activity" go and change the main activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, switch-statement, application-settings

In the Activity Settings shown below, in general, the switch, i want when is true to have "on"/"appear"/"display"/"launch" activity_main_one to the screen and when it is false to have on activity_main_two to the screen:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Posting relevant code snippets here would be nice.

Comment: yes i know, but i believe my code is wrong :P if i put my code here the output will be the same, someone will light me with the right code and it will be something different, so that why i didnt put any code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Otherwise, good luck getting an answer with the "right code" :-)

Comment: i cant understand, did i ask of something weird? or i am not very helpful of giving info of what i want to learn..because i believe i ask of something really easy and understandable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void loadPref() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    boolean isTrue = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Guest_Mode_Key", true);
    if (isTrue) {
        View Guest =  findViewById(R.id.guest_include);
        View User = findViewById(R.id.user_include);
        Guest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        User.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    } else {
        View Guest =  findViewById(R.id.guest_include);
        View User = findViewById(R.id.user_include);
        Guest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        User.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

.

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/guest_include"
    layout="@layout/content_one"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/user_include"
    layout="@layout/content_two"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

I created two <*include> tags and set the first to "Visible" and the second "Gone", i found how to get the data from the settings activity it was simple and then i created an if when the switch is true etc. and for the end i just call loadPref()

@DaveNOTDavid - I was lucky after all ;)